# Make and use external resource in android studio

Tags: android, external, android-resources

I'm developing an android app that has large resources (Gifs and PNGs) .
If include this resources in my project, app size increase, so I decided to push this items to an external resources and download it after app first run.
But i don't have any technical idea about how to create and use external resource in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Make them available through a http(s) source on your server, then use `HttpsURLConnection` or similar apis to download them to your app local storage.

Another approach could be using the `glide` library which is designed for remote images. https://github.com/bumptech/glide

The path for your local storage can be retrieved via `context.getFilesDir()`. This is the path of the private files folder for the installed app.
There you can simply create/remove files at will.

Your app then needs to open those images via the `BitmapFactory` class and not through `R.xxx.xxx`.